# SetFixedPosition of Parapgraph or Image results in wrong display order

Tags: itext, itext7

With itext7 in VB.NET i create a PDF.
There I have this code-snippet:

```
Dim img As New Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(imagePath))
img.SetWidth(varImgWidth)
img.SetHeight(varImgHeight)
img.SetFixedPosition(100,100)
doc.add(img)
doc.add(new Paragraph("This is a test"))
```

The set position of the image overlaps with the text of the parapgraph. I expected, that the image is set to the document at the given position and then - afterwards - the text is "printed" above the image, because it is defined "after" the image in the code.

But what I see is, that the image positioned with SetFiexedPosition is always above other elements. I get the behaviour when positioning a text via SetFixedPosition on the Paragraph containing the text.

My question is: Is there any possibility to tell the element which is positioned, that it should be behind other elements.

Or - better question - is there any "positioning possibility" which allows a positioning of an element and considering the "order" in which it is "printed" in the code.

Do you understand what I mean?
(Sorry, it´s not easy for me to express it in English)

Thank you for any help

Regards
Benjamin

Comment: Hi.

Is there nobody who knows any hint? Or is it impossible to do it?

Comment: The renderer hierarchies appear to indeed draw the positioned objects last. But what you can of course do is to start by explicitly drawing the image on the canvas of the current page and only thereafter add content using the document object...

Comment: Hi Benjamin, can you let us know which version of iText you are using, attach the whole relevant code snipped (working with iText), and the resultant PDF? I cannot reproduce the issue at the moment